# How do I convert a string with "object.value" name to a variable that can be used with the play function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function with two parameters that i use to play a specific audio file. The audio files are in an object.

```
const object = {
    audio: new Audio(`link`)
};

function play(par1, par2){
    let element = par1 + `.` + par2;
    console.log(element);
    window[element].play();
}
```

But when I call the function like so:

```
play(object, audio);
```

It does not work.

I expected it to playback the audio i defined in object.audio.

Comment: Seems you want `window[par1][par2].play()`? Or better yet, if you're passing `object`, not `'object'`, then use `par1[par2].play()`.

Comment: Why not simply pass `object.audio`, instead of passing `object` and the string `'audio'` separately?

Comment: You already have a reference to an [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), you should be able to play it like [`object.audio.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play). What do you need `window` for, and what do you expect `window[element]` to do?

Comment: You say it "does not work". can you tell us what is happening? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [JS objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) to know the proper way to access value from an object.

```
const object = {
    audio: new Audio(`link`)
};

function play(par1, par2){
    let element = par1[par2];
    console.log(element);
    element.play();
}

play(object, "audio");
```

Comment: When accessing properties in bracket notation, the property value in the brackets is converted to a string (unless it's a symbol). So your `window[element]` should be equivalent to `window["[object HTMLAudioElement]"]`, which I assume to evaluate to undefined.

Comment: You're right. Updated the answer.

Comment: @j.ian.le Okay so you seem to have misunderstood me a bit - and that's my bad. I didn't mean a play function that I had made, but rather the HTMLMediaElement.play() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play